# Windows Phone 8 in app purchases: Can't find item in catalogue

Tags: windows-phone-8, in-app-purchase

I am trying to set up in-app purchasing in my Windows Phone 8 app. I can get it working in debug using MockIAPLib but when I try run it in release connecting to the Windows store it is not working, and I get the onscreen message `Can't find item in catalogue`
I have created my product and it is in the Beta store.
I have put my App product Id into the App WMAppManifest.xml file, so it can communicate with the store.

I can tell that my App is able to see the product from the store as I can see the license info, i.e.

```
LicenseInformation licenseInformation;
licenseInformation = CurrentApp.LicenseInformation;
productLicense = licenseInformation.ProductLicenses[strInAppProductId];
```

However I can not see the product listing

```
ListingInformation listing = await CurrentApp.LoadListingInformationByProductIdsAsync(new string[] { strInAppProductId });
listing.ProductListings.Count();
```

Nor can I buy the app

```
await CurrentApp.RequestProductPurchaseAsync(strInAppProductId , false);
```

I have now added multiple products on the Dev Center, I can see the under the license but not under listing or RequestProductPurchaseAsync.

Please help!

Thanks

Comment: I don't think this works if the app is not deployed from the Store. (But I might be wrong.) Is this the case? Or does it not work within an app that's already in the Store?

Comment: My understanding from what I have read is that it should work as long as I put the product id from the version I have deployed to the store into my App WMAppManifest.xml file. It is only in the Beta store, so I am not clear on whether that will effect how it behaves.

Comment: Oh, yes, in that case I think it should work. Are you sure the device you're testing on has Internet connection? Also, if it's a beta, you could upload a version that lists the purchases and see if it works when you download it from the Store.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I cracked it... I had this line missing from the top of the file

```
using Store = Windows.ApplicationModel.Store;
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
            var listing = await CurrentApp.LoadListingInformationAsync();
            var obj= listing.ProductListings.FirstOrDefault(
                       p => p.Value.ProductId == strInAppProductId );                 
             var receipt = await CurrentApp.RequestProductPurchaseAsync(obj.Value.ProductId, true);
```

Also, make sure that the strInAppProductId has correct value for product id.

Comment: Thanks, I have tried this but I get the same result.
I output the strInAppProductId  to the log before using it so I know it is correct.

Also, with this code... 
                var listing = await CurrentApp.LoadListingInformationAsync();
                Debugger.Log(1, "Info", "License: CheckLicense(): listing.ProductListings.Count() = " + listing.ProductListings.Count() + "\n");

The listing.ProductListings.Count() comes out as 0. I have 2 products associated with my App...

Comment: Are you sure that you copy and paste application id from Dev centre to WMAppManifest.xml then rebuild the project to get updated xap file before uploading it to the store.??